# What is the performance penalty of operator overloading STL

Tags: java, c++, stl, memory-leaks

I like STL a lot. It makes coding algorithms very convenient since it provides you will all the primitives like parition, find, binary_search, iterators, priority_queue etc. Plus you dont have to worry about memory leaks at all.

My only concern is the performance penalty of operator overloading that is necessary to get STL working.
For comparison, I think it relies that == provides the needed semantics. We need to overload ==operator if we are adding our classes to a container.

How much efficiency am I losing for this convenience?

Another aside question regarding memory leaks:

1. Can memory leak ever happen when using STL containers?
2. Can a memory leak ever happen in Java?

Comment: Of course, memory leaks can happen in Java - see here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/

Comment: An overloaded operator is basically a method.

Comment: Nice link @schnaader.  Wish I could give you a +1 for comments.

Comment: @ajay In the future I would split things like this into two questions.  Your title for this post has nothing to do with your question about Java and memory leaks.

Comment: Why would you think operator overloading would cause a performance penalty?  I'm puzzled by this.  Also, the standard questions:  Are you sure you have a performance problem?  Check your measurements.  Where does the profiler say the problem is?  What's your baseline performance, and what's your target, and what's your plan for measuring?  We don't cotton much to micro-optimizers in these here parts.

Comment: What would be an alternative? Copying implementation of std::sort, and replacing all comparisons with inline hard code for that type / predicate?

Comment: Voted to close 'Not a real question' due to two wildly divergent, unrelated questions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using stl algortithms on generic types, you have to supply the comparison logic in some way. Operator overloading has no performance penalty over any other function and may (like any other function) be inlined to remove any function call overhead.

Many standard containers and algorithms also use `std::less` and hence by default `<` rather than `==`.

The standard containers don't themselves leak, but you can use them to hold objects (such as pointers) which don't necessarily clean up memory that they 'own'.

It's difficult to leak memory in java, but that doesn't mean you can't get into trouble by failing to have good object ownership semantics and it doesn't mean that you can't use up all the available memory and crash.

Answer (score 4):

I'll leave the C++ answers to the previous posters, but 100% yes you can memory leak in Java.  It tends to be really difficult to find too unless you have some good memory profiling tools to look at.  In general, memory leaks in automated garbage collection languages (e.g. Java, Python, etc.) occur when you repeatedly instantiate objects, but either A. don't clean them up when you're done with them (e.g. calling "close" on  a database connection) or B. continue to persist other objects that point to them (e.g. Hashtables) so that the automated garbage collector can never garbage collect them.

If your application is in what you think should be a stable state and you get one of these:

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

You're in for some fun debuggin  ;)

Comment: Perhaps this is too much of a C++ slant, but is it really a memory leak if the memory is used by objects that you still have a reference to in the application? In this situation the memory can still (theoretically) be found from objects in the application. A 'true' memory leak is where the last reference to some memory has actually been destroyed so there simply isn't a pointer to the memory in the application at all.

Comment: I think the definition changes a bit in a language with automated garbage collection...to me a memory leak in one of these languages is anything a programmer does to prevent the garbage collector from cleaning up references to objects that the programmer is done with and is expecting to be garbage collected. Automated garbage collectors are smart enough to clean up objects that no longer have any other objects referencing them. To persist in memory in Java, there still must be active references to the object laying around.

Answer (score 1):

Since operator overloading simply results in a function call, and you would have to write a function to do the work anyways, the overhead is zero.  Operator overloading is just a convenience so you can do things like x == y instead of x.equals(y) or x < y instead of x.compaterTo(y).  The compiler essentially generates something like: x.==(y) or x.<(y) (that won't compile, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 1):

The "penalty" is actually a bonus.

Let's take the most typical of algorithms, sorting. C does not have operator overloading. As a result, `qsort` takes a function pointer. Each comparison uses an indirect function call (at runtime). C++ does have operator overloading. For `std::sort`, each comparison is a direct call (fixed by linker) or inlined (by compiler). This is far mroe effective. It's not uncommon for `std::sort` to be 6 times faster than `qsort`.

In general, operator overloading makes it a lot easier to express the "default" functions for a type, in a way that can be exploited by other code and compilers. The alternatives are far less efficient. Either they rely on macros (which hurt programmers) or they rely on function pointers (which hurt optimizers and CPUs.)

Answer (score 1):

> My only concern is the performance penalty of operator overloading that is necessary to get STL working. For comparison, I think it relies that == provides the needed semantics. We need to overload ==operator if we are adding our classes to a container.

It is nonexistent. Your overloaded operator is implemented as a function call. And if you didn't overload the operator, you'd need to define a function to use instead. So the performance is **exactly** the same, just with a cleaner syntax.

Answer (score 0):

[What is the performance penalty of operator overloading STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1800423/what-is-the-performance-penalty-of-operator-overloading-stl/1803143#1803143)

In addition to this you can always have your operators inline this will not even have the penalty of a function call.